# Order creation for multi-vendor setup

Tags: orders, payment-gateway, sales-order, multi-vendor, order-splitting

Initially it looked very simple to me but now i realize that it is little more complicated then i thought it would be.

I am working on marketplace website. Where the system will have buyers as well as sellers. However, the experience is going to be seamless for buyer they will see all the product under same Quote/Order. However there will be an extra attribute with each order item for seller information.

Now, my question is moreover along the line of order creation, If we want to provide a unified view for all the product from different sellers to buyer but at the same time sellers will see only their products under the order.

My **first approach** was to split the order before user is redirected for payment. which i think is wrong approach because of two main reasons:

- I think it's very wrong experience for buyers, as they will need to
  understand why the order gets split into multiple suborders.
- Also, the way payment gateways work is, it gets the information from session
  order object. Which in this case captures only first order and ignores all other and so partial payment is received at our end.

**Second obvious approach** is to not split it, In this case Magento also provide way to split the invoice and shipping but I see a problem here when i want to show seller about their order.

To show seller their order If i have two sellers `SellerA` and `SellerB` in my shop I am showing the order to both the sellers but with condition to show only their order item under their Dashboard and same i need to do when I want to inform sellers about new order via email.

but I feel this isn't right approach as this will require changes everywhere i need to display their order information to sellers and do total calculation accordingly. There should be a better way to do it.

Any suggestion on what is the optimal or at-least better way to achieve this?

Comment: @Serpyre, Thanks and the which solution is suited for it. Also, what would you think is most efficient way to handle this in Magento?

Comment: Magento is not well suited for Marketplaces, as per the comments above. Consider using [X-Cart](http://www.x-cart.com/) instead.

Comment: Thanks @JasonS, Any idea on how order creation works with X-Cart?

Comment: There is the uMarketplace extension from Unirgy - worth a look.

Comment: Hi @ben, Thanks for your reply. We looked into uMarketplace from Unirgy. It works the same way, how we are looking in terms of order creation but not sure, how they have customized Magento to achieve this. Also, the reason why we aren't looking to use uMarketplace as extension at this moment because it differs significantly then how we are planning to build.

Comment: You are looking at extensive customization of Magento to achieve what you want. Might be best to work with an existing vendor. I recommended unirgy because, well, he's the orignal architect of Magento ;-)

Comment: Oh :) Yeah, It looks same to me. Thanks @ben

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure on how the sellers would see their orders, but I am assuming it would be via Magento admin. So create a separate admin tab/view and show only the order items and order information pertaining to that particular seller. You could also use ACL's to block them from viewing the default Magento orders in the admin. I am not sure how its handled in the payments though. I know for a fact that PayPal Adaptive payments has a way to do that.

Comment: Using ACL i can manage the access to certain functionality but still i'll need to customize view of order information. My question is more along the lines of handling the order creation.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Free Magento extension for multi vendor (seller) site it's called :

[Marketplace](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/marketplace-2.html)

> Marketplace plug-in provides the necessary functionalities for a
>   seller to sell their products online. After approval from the store
>   administrator, sellers can add products and manage order processing on
>   their own.